# 301 redirect wrong (to server path)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect "`adm`" folder to "`administrator`"

my `.htaccess` code:

```
Redirect 301 /adm /administrator
```

But i go to the url:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/home2/myuser/public_html/administrator
```

How to do this correctly?
Can `RewriteRule` with flags `[R=301,L]` do the work? Because I go to the same page with `RewriteRule` or `Redirect`

Thanks.

Comment: The redirect target has to be a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this may not be a problem of your rewrite rules but maybe something wrong about your configuration.

Anyway try a rewriterule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/adm(/(.*))$ /administrator$1 [QSA,R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Tried, but go to the url `http://www.mywebsite.com/home2/myuser/public_html/administrator`. I have tried add `RewriteBase /` but none..

Comment: Try shiplu's answer then... :)

Comment: well, I have done the job =)
the problem is `Redirect 301` target (as Samuel Bierwagen said) need to be a url, not a folder. But, with your answer I remembered about `rewriteBase` before any rule, which solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

RedirectMatch directive would do

```
RedirectMatch permanent  /adm(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/administrator$1
```